# controlling the order of json serialization in typescript

Tags: json, typescript, serialization, geojson

I am serializing a *Typescript* class object:

```
class Geometry {
    public abstract type: string;
    public abstract coordinates: Coordinates | number[];
}

class Point extends Geometry {
    public readonly type: string = "Point";

    constructor(public coordinates: Coordinate | number[]) {
        super();
    }
}
```

using `JSON.stringify(new Point([10, 10]));`

So far so good, however, this is ultimately being inserted into a *GeoJSON* object and order of the properties matters.  What I'm getting is:

```
{"coordinates":[10,10],"type":"Point"}
```

What I need is:

```
{"type":"Point","coordinates":[10,10]}
```

---

If do not declare the `public coordinates` in the constructor and assign them:

```
constructor(coordinates: Coordinate | number[]) {
   super();
   this.coordinates = coordinates;
}
```

the result is correct.  Being a minimalist, I'm trying to get this to work with the constructor using the public parameter.

Is there a way to control the order of the properties in the `JSON.stringify(-)` method?

---

**Giving an alternate answer to myself**

The real problem was with the `properties` value of a feature (outside the scope of the original question).  By overriding the [`toJSON`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#toJSON()_behavior) method on the object it is possible to control how an object serializes itself. I added the the following to my `Geometry` class and all was well.

```
public toJSON() {
    return {
        type: this.type,
        coordinates: this.coordinates,
    };
}
```

I made to further decorate my upstream `Feature` and `FeatureCollection` classes as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass a second parameter to `JSON.stringify` with an array with the name of the properties in the desired order.

For example:

```
JSON.stringify(new Point([10, 10]), ['type', 'coordinates']);
```

Comment: thanks for pointing me in the right direction and ultimately making me _RTFM_.

Comment: Glad to help :)